# Python string mutation

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop

I am trying to loop though a string and convert underscores to camel case. Example) my_string --> myString

I have posted my working code below. Can someone help me figure out the hole in my logic?

```
            
def to_camel_ca (string):
    camel_string = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == '_':
            camel_string = camel_string + string[i + 1].replace(string[i+1], string[i+1].capitalize())
        elif string[i] != "_":
            camel_string = camel_string + string[i]
        print(camel_string)
    return camel_string
    
    
to_camel_ca('my_string') 



#returns

m
my
myS
mySs
mySst
mySstr
mySstri
mySstrin
mySstring

'mySstring'
```

Many thanks!

Comment: you convert `_` to `S` after that you should skip the next letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the camelCase string will be shorter.  When you encounter an underscore, and capitalize the next letter, you need to skip a letter in the source string.  Here is a way to do that:

```
def to_camel_ca (string):
    camel_string = ""
    skip = False
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if skip:
            skip = False
            continue
        if string[i] == '_':
            camel_string = camel_string + string[i + 1].replace(string[i+1], string[i+1].capitalize())
            skip = True
        elif string[i] != "_":
            camel_string = camel_string + string[i]
        print(camel_string)
    return camel_string
```

**Example**

```
to_camel_ca('my_test_string')
```

> ```
> m
> my
> myT
> myTe
> myTes
> myTest
> myTestS
> myTestSt
> myTestStr
> myTestStri
> myTestStrin
> myTestString
> ```

---

**A Slightly Different Approach**

Here's is a slightly simpler approach.  When an underscore is encountered, make a note to capitalize the next letter.  It has the advantage of handling input strings which end in underscore.

```
def to_camel_ca (string):
    camel_string = ""
    capitalize = False
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == '_':
            capitalize = True
            continue
        elif capitalize:
            camel_string = camel_string + string[i].capitalize()
            capitalize = False
        elif string[i] != "_":
            camel_string = camel_string + string[i]
        print(camel_string)
    return camel_string
```

Comment: Note: You have a bug if the input string ends in an underscore.  An array index out of range error will occur when you attempt to access the letter after the underscore.  You can fix this with a check of `if i == len(string): continue` before accessing `[i + 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a character after an underscore is processed/added to the camelString twice: one when the `if` finds an underscore and again when that character itself matches the elif condition.